# How to transfer .wav audio files through an Android app?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth

I have to make an app that can send and recieve audio files (in .wav files specifically) via bluetooth. How can I go about it? Where can I find the right documentation? Is there any easier way to do this .wav file tranfer if not bluetooth? I have successfully paired the devices.

Comment: What does it matter that it is a wav file? Nothing. Its just a file.

Comment: What you did not tell us is who is going to receive the file? Or who did sent it. Or who is on the other side.